# Autofac with MVC 4 action filter property injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I am using the Nuget MVC3 integration package for Autofac with MVC4. It mostly works (constructor injection with Controllers is working great) but it does not inject registered services into action filter properties.

This is my registration in Global.asax.cs:

```
builder.RegisterType<AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>().As(typeof(IUserService)).InstancePerHttpRequest();
// 5) action filters
builder.RegisterType<SetCultureAttribute>().As<IActionFilter>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Then in the `SetCultureAttribute` I have this:

```
public IUserService _userService { get; set; } // it doesn't get injected, null
```

Nor does this work in the constructor of the attribute:

```
_userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<AspNetMembershipProviderWrapper>(); // always returns null
```

`DependencyResolver.Current.GetService()` also returns null for all other registered services when called within the action filter's constructor (I tried it out in the Debug windows to test it).

So I guess something is not working right. Is it ok to use MVC3 integration or should I use MVC4 Nuget package (which says it's for RC)?

Is there anything else I could try to make this work?

Comment: In you sample `_userService` is a public readonly *field* but property injection (as the name implies) needs properties (e.g. `public IUserService UserService { get; set;}`) . So is it a typo in your sample or the source of your problem?

Comment: You were right and I updated the code but it makes no difference. Everything would be fine if property injection didn't work and DependecyResolver.Current.GetService worked but it doesn't either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get ActionFilter injection working you need to register the provider, which I don't see in your example:

```
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

There is doc on that here: 
http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration3

In either case, you registered the service as IUserService, so that's how you'd have to resolve it.

```
_userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
```

You don't need to register the attribute. Check the wiki link above for more.

Comment: wow thanks, how could I have missed the IUserService type in the GetService parameter?? :)

Comment: The filter provider was registered though, it's the GetService<IUserService) that did the trick.;)